# Get Raw data value from a go struct

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, go, kubernetes, yaml

Im struggling to read value from yaml file, the value from the [`raw data`](https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery/blob/master/pkg/runtime/types.go#L94) struct , I need to get value like following , I want to get the `cidr` value and `zone[0].name`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)


type Provider struct {
    Type string
    
    InfrastructureConfig *runtime.RawExtension

}

type RawExtension struct {
    // Raw is the underlying serialization of this object.
    // TODO: Determine how to detect ContentType and ContentEncoding of 'Raw' data.
    Raw []byte `json:"-" protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=raw"`
    Object Object `json:"-"`
}

func main() {
        // inside the row it should have the value from the yaml
       
    object.provider.InfrastructureConfig.Raw.
}
```

The yaml looks like following

```
 infrastructureConfig:
    kind: InfrastructureConfig
    apiVersion: v1
       networks:
          vpc:
            cidr: aaaa
          zones:
            - name: vm
              internal: true
```

if something isn't clear please let me know.

I've tried something like `val,err := json.Marshal(object.provider.InfrastructureConfig.Raw)`

In the val (using the debugger) I got the value `"e30="` which is not what I want I want to get the `cidr` value which is `aaaa`

but I didn't able to get the data ...

This is the type of `*runtime.RawExtension`

https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery/blob/master/pkg/runtime/types.go#L94

Comment: What is `object` in your main? Your code doesn't compile, you reference `runtime` but don't import it. How do you load the YAML into your code? Is your question how to load YAML data inside a `[]byte`? If so, of what relevance are the surrounding types? Your YAML data has a syntax error, is that your problem? Please edit the question to show a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: why you do tag json"-"